# Jquery for each closest, calculate and replace values

Tags: jquery

I am having a bit of trouble trying to replace calculated values. In this function we are trying to use the value of the hidden text box calculate a discount and replace the original price with the new discounted value. I can get the discounts and values, but it will not replace the values into the div..I am thinking my "closest" is not working...Any thoughts what I am doing wrong here.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cal_discount").click(function() {

        $(".price_val").each(function() {
            var Percent = $('#percent_dis').val();
            var price = $(this).val();
            var existing = $(this).closest('.existing_price');
            var new_price = (price - (price * (Percent / 100)));
            var formatted = new_price.toFixed(2);
            existing.text(formatted);
        });
    });
});

<div class="existing_price" style="float:left">22</div>
<input  type="hidden"  class="price_val" value="22" />

<input name="percent_dis" type="text" id="percent_dis" size="3" /> %      <img src="admin/images/btn/cal_discount.png" width="97" height="17" style="float:left; margin-right:10px; margin-top:5px; cursor:pointer" id="cal_discount" />
```

Comment: Why not just use `$('.existing_price');` instead of `closest()`?

Comment: @NADL Obviously there are more `.price_val` and `.existing_price` in his code.

Comment: @Vega - It's not always obvious to everyone.

Comment: @j08691 This `$(".price_val").each(function() {` is what made it obvious.. but I agree that OP has to mention that.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with that the `</div>` after the 22 should not be there..

`.closest()` goes upwards the DOM hierarchy .. with up meaning ancestors...

so it looks for the first ancestor that matches the selector..

since the `.price_val` is not inside the `.existing_price` it will not find it..

Changing your code to

```
<div class="existing_price" style="float:left">
  <span class="value">22</span>
  <input  type="hidden"  class="price_val" value="22" />
</div>
```

and js

```
    $(".price_val").each(function() {
        var Percent = $('#percent_dis').val();
        var price = $(this).val();
        var existing = $(this).siblings('.value');
        var new_price = (price - (price * (Percent / 100)));
        var formatted = new_price.toFixed(2);
        existing.text(formatted);
    });
```

would fix the issue.

Comment: +1 A better approach than what OP has. Even though `</div>` may be intentional or not.

Comment: Any thoughts why I cannot get this to calculate more than once even after changing .click(function() to .live('click', function()?

Comment: @Greg.. ah yes... (*`live` is not relevant*).. we overwrite the hidden input with the `.text()` method.. updating answer

Comment: *enclosed the value in a `<span>` and used the `.siblings()` method to find the relevant `input` element*

Answer (score 2):

What you need is `.prev` not closest that is if the prev element is always the `div.existing_price`

Try

```
var existing = $(this).prev(); //should return div for your existing markup
```

Comment: @GregBurris Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10356902/297641 approach. Definitely a better markup than yours. It shouldn't affect as it is `input type=hidden`

Comment: @GregBurris It is the linke to Gaby's answer below

Answer (score 0):

Closest only works when the element is a descendant, not a sibling - use `prev` instead.